# How to get the value returned by a promise in Protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

```
function toWindow(tab){
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            browser.switchTo().window(handles[tab]); 
        return handles.length; 
    });
}

console.log(toWindow(1));
```

My expected output: should display the total count of opened tabs in a browser.

Solutions I have tried:

- make a global variable to receive the handles.length value - still `undefined`
- add return before `browser.getAllWindowHandles()`... still `undefined`

Comment: 1. You don't return anything from the `toWindow` function. 2. `browser.getAllWindowHandles` returns a promise, you need to handle it as one via `async/await` or the promise API.

Comment: I'm new to javascript and protractor, how to handle a promise with async/await? I really need some examples.

Comment: i just want to use handles.length 
outside of this block of code:

browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            browser.switchTo().window(handles[tab]); 
        return handles.length; 
    });